# How to rename a flow in NiFi Registry?

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-nifi-registry

NiFi Registry currently allows renaming **buckets**, but not versioned **flows**. How can I rename one?
I've looked into the documentation but I can't find any solution.

*I am using NiFi `v1.9.0`.*

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct rename option; instead create a new versioned flow object via the rest interface and copy across any versions you want to keep.

Comment: Do you think that there would be a _messy_ way to do it by changing values directly in the NiFi Registry PostgreSQL database?

Comment: Yes that is probably possible; you'd have to modify the database and the flow name and ensure the UUIDs don't get messed up, but I have not tried it.